# How to get all the elements in an array but not in another array in HIVE?

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql

For example, I have two columns of arrays now:

```
id     col1     col2
A      [1, 3]   [1, 2, 3]
B      [2]      [1, 2, 3]
```

what I want is all the elements in `col2` but not in `col1`:

```
id     output
A      [2]
B      [1, 3]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Using `Pandas` this is one line job

Answer (score 2):

Explode col2 array, use array_contains to check each element is in another array, collect array again for elements not in col1 array

```
select t.id, 
       collect_set(case when array_contains(t.col1, e.elem) then NULL else e.elem end) as result  
  from my_table t 
       lateral view explode(t.col2) e as elem
 group by t.id
```